# What is the meaning of the "spawn" command in Linux (Centos6)

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, sftp, expect

I need to know how to set up a cron job that automatically connects to a remote server,  then changes to a directory and downloads all the files in that directory to local.

I think I have to use SFTP but I saw the following command using "spawn" in a shell script, and I am confused as to how it is used and why:

```
spawn  sftp user@ipaddress
cd xxx/inbox
mget *
```

Will this work to download a remote directory?

Comment: it creates a new process: http://www.astro.virginia.edu/class/oconnell/astr511/idl_5.1_html/idl1a9.htm I don't even have that command. You should run spawn -v; spawn -V spawn --version; spawn --usage; spawn --help; spawn -h; spawn -help; help spawn; man spawn and see if you can find any information about where that command really comes from. Or at least tell us what OS you are on. It would also be useful to know which ftp clients you have installed (ncftp, lftp, ftp, etc) and if you need to authenticate against the server with a username and password.

Comment: Which shell is it? Does the first line of the script start with `#!`? Could you please tell us what is in the first line?  Did you find the lines you show here somewhere like this or did you put them together from multiple sources? The spawn command looks like a command of an expect script but the following two commands look like sftp commands (i.e. sftp batch).

Comment: Did you finally manage to setup the cron job?

Comment: not really i am doing it on amazon for now, thanks for your answer i will try that and see.. thanksagain..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case, `spawn` is most probably a command of [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) scripting language which allows automation of interactive program operations. In such a case, `spawn` runs an external command from the expect script. Your script example is missing a [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) sequence (first line starting with `#!`), indicating the `expect` interpreter, and, as such, will not be interpreted by `expect` when executed directly.

Password authentication with `sftp` is limited to the interactive mode; To control `sftp` in interactive mode, you can use the following expect script example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout 20    # max. 20 seconds waiting for the server response

set user username
set pass your-pass
set host the-host-address
set dir  server-dir

spawn sftp $user@$host
expect assword:

send "$pass\r"
expect sftp>

send "cd $dir\r"
expect sftp>

send "mget *\r"
expect sftp>

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Another possibility is to use public-key authentication, which is more secure (see [Setup SFTP to Use Public-Key Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231626/320437)). In such a case, you can simply use `sftp` directly in batch mode:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
user=username
host=the-host-address
dir=server-dir

sftp -b - "$user@$host" <<+++EOF+++
cd "$dir"
mget *
exit
+++EOF+++
```